# $Lf^*$ is fully faithful

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, derived-functors

I don't understand the smoothness condition in the following theorem,

Let $f: X\longrightarrow Y$ be a projective morphism of $\underline{smooth}$ projective varieties such that $Rf_*\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_Y$. Then the functor

\begin{equation}
Lf^* : D^b(Y)\longrightarrow D^b(X)
\end{equation}
is fully faithful.

The proof is easy,
\begin{equation}
Hom_{D(X)}(Lf^*\mathcal{F}^{\bullet},Lf^*\mathcal{F}^{\bullet}) \simeq Hom_{D(Y)} (\mathcal{F}^{\bullet},Rf_*Lf^*\mathcal{F}^{\bullet}) \simeq Hom_{D(Y)}(\mathcal{F}^{\bullet},\mathcal{F}^{\bullet}\otimes Rf_*\mathcal{O}_X)\simeq Hom_{D(Y)}(\mathcal{F}^{\bullet},\mathcal{F}^{\bullet}).
\end{equation}

As far as I know, the projection formula works for any proper morphism, so why we need both varieties to be smooth?

Can we generalize it to the case which $X$ is smooth and $Y$ is singular?
(Sasha explained why this is impossible, but what about the other case, i.e. $X$ singular, and $Y$ is smooth)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Smoothness is not necessary. What is important is that $f$ has finite $Tor$-dimension (otherwise $Lf^*$ does not preserve boundedness); a sufficient (but not necessary) condition for this is smoothness of $Y$.

On the other hand, it is impossible to have $X$ smooth and $Y$ singular. Indeed, in this case one can find objects $F,G \in D^b(Y)$ with $\dim Ext^\bullet(F,G) = \infty$ (e.g. $F = G = O_y$ for $y \in Sing(Y)$), while for any objects of $D^b(X)$ the analogous dimension is finite.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For the second question, I actually wanted to ask about the case $X$ is singular, but $Y$ is smooth, I'll edit the post.

Comment: That is of course possible. For instance, take $Y = Spec(k)$ and $X$ any proper variety with $H^\bullet(X,O_X) = k$.